# Initializing matrix in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm trying to initialise a 4x4 matrix and then assign values to the matrix later through a function call. This yields an error;

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

I know this error occurs when I am trying access unavailable or unassigned location in memory. But according to Eigen documentation example, [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialAdvancedInitialization.html) is how the do it.

This is my header file initialisation.

```
    MatrixX4d T;
```

This is my implementation file function call.

```
MatrixX4d RobotArm::substitute(double theta, double alpha, double a, double d)
{
    RobotArm::T << cos(theta), -sin(theta), 0, a,
               (sin(theta)*cos(alpha)), (cos(theta)*cos(alpha)), -sin(alpha),   (-sin(alpha)*d),
               (sin(theta)*sin(alpha)),(cos(theta)*sin(alpha)), cos(alpha), (cos(alpha)*d),
               0, 0, 0, 1;
    cout << T;
    return T;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MatrixX4d T
```

is half-dynamic matrix.

Instead,

```
Matrix4d T
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MatrixX4d as a 4x4, resize it first to be 4x4.

```
T.resize(4, Eigen::NoChange);
```